# Why there is very little but recognizable difference between my regular and cuda multiplication of image?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

There is very little but recognizable difference between my regular and cuda multiplication of image. Regular image is little lighter.

main function's part:

```
Mat im1 = imread("1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
int size = im1.rows * im1.cols;
int i = 0;
uint8_t * d_a;
im1 = im1 * 3; //this made image a little lighter comparatively.
imshow("Original", im1);

cudaMalloc(&d_a, sizeof(uint8_t)*size);
cudaMemcpy(d_a, &im1.data[0], sizeof(uint8_t)*size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

dim3 threadsPerBlock(im1.cols);
dim3 numBlocks(im1.rows);


colonal << <numBlocks, threadsPerBlock >> >(d_a);
cudaMemcpy(&im1.data[0], d_a, sizeof(uint8_t)*size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaFree(d_a);

imshow("new", im1);
waitKey();
```

Here is the Kernel:

```
__global__
void colonal(uint8_t * a)
{
    int x = blockIdx.x;
    int y = threadIdx.x;
    int width = blockDim.x;
    int index = (x * width)+y;

    a[index] = a[index] * 3;
}
```

Comment: When you're asking for debugging help, you should provide a [mcve]  What you've provided is not.

Comment: When the question is basically "spot my trivial mistake from this incomplete example" you are not contributing anything which will help others or add to the existing body of useful CUDA information on [SO]. That is why this question was down voted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't expect both images you are displaying to be the same.  This line of code:

```
im1 = im1 * 3;
```

actually modifies the `im1` data.  Each `im1` pixel is now 3 times larger.

Then you are copying this modified data to the device:

```
cudaMemcpy(d_a, &im1.data[0], sizeof(uint8_t)*size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

and multiplying it **again** by 3.

If you want both images to look the same,  instead of this:

```
im1 = im1 * 3; //this made image a little lighter comparatively.
imshow("Original", im1);
```

I would suggest doing this:

```
Mat im2 = im1 * 3; 
imshow("Original", im2);
```

The issue should also be pretty obvious if you just print out a few pixels numerical values in each case.  In your original code you should see the pixels increasing by a factor of 3 *twice*.